# Scheduling events in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

SO sorry if this is a duplicate, I tried searching for this but wasnt sure what search terms to use and didnt really find anything.

I have a Ruby on Rails app that will be used to send text messages out to users that contain a link to a multiple choice question probably using clickatell. The questions have a date and time associated with them. I want to make the ruby on rails app automatically send those SMS messages to the users' phones on those specified dates.

I don't really know how one would go about doing this. Can anyone point me in the general direction of a a way to schedule events like this in ruby on rails. I don't need an exact solution, maybe if someone could just clarify what exactly this is called so I can find some resources on line.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the sending out your questions is not reoccuring? In this case I would not do this via a cronjob. I would do this via: https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler

So whenever a question is getting scheduled you just add it to the delayed queue and resque-scheduler handles moving them on the correct working queue when its time has come.

This way you don't have to worry about some sort of polling cronjob, this will be done by resque-scheduler automatically. You also get asynchronous handling of sending out the SMSes via resque for free. So if you have to send lots and lots of SMS you can run them in parallel.

So it would go like this:

1. when a question is saved, you queue a message on the delayed queue in the future for sending out the question
2. when the date comes up, the message is moved onto 'ready to send'-queue, which is in charge of gathering all the users the question needs to be sent to.
3. for each of those users you create another message on the 'ready to send'-queue
4. the 'ready to send'-queue will then send out the actual SMSes

You then can run many workers on the 'ready to send'-queue and have the SMSes be sent out in parallel. You also get error handling for free with resque, it gahers all messages that resulted in an exception in a 'failure' queue, which you can then debug or reschedule again

Comment: +1 for resque and resque-scheduler, we use it with great success on a completely different project

Comment: Nice, this is a really helpful and detailed response. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Anytime, I realy like Resque :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule events.

Comment: so I could use this to make the application, say, check every 30 minutes to see which questions have become available and send the appropriate text messages?

Comment: Yeah, it sets up a cron for you. I usually set it up s.t. it runs a rake task.