# Strange behavior with a resque scheduler job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

so some context, I got some advice here:

> [Scheduling events in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710013/scheduling-events-in-ruby-on-rails)

aand have been tying to implement it today. I cant seem to make it work though. this is my scheduler job that is used to move my questions around between a delayed queue and a ready to send out queue (i've since decided to use email instead of SMS)

```
require 'Assignment'
require 'QuestionMailer'
module SchedulerJob
  @delayed_queue = :delayed_queue
  @ready_queue

  def self.perform()
    @delayed_queue.each do |a|
      if(Time.now >= a.question.schedule)
        @ready_queue << a  
        @delayed_queue.delete(a)
      end
    end
    push_questions
  end

  def self.gather()
    assignments = Assignment.find :all
      assignments.each do |a|
      @delayed_queue << a unless @delayed_queue.include? a
    end
  end

  private
  def self.push_questions
    @ready_queue.each do |a|
      QuestionMailer.question(a)
    end
  end

end
```

I use a callback on_create to call the gather method every time an assignment is created, and then the perform action actually does the sending of emails when resque runs.

I'm getting a strange error from the callback though. 
 `` undefined method `include?' for :delayed_queue:Symbol ``

here is the code from the assignment model

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :user_id, :question_id , :response , :correct
  after_create :queue_assignments


  def grade
    self.correct = (response == self.question.solution) unless response == nil
  end

  def queue_assignments
    SchedulerJob.gather
  end
```

Any ideas what's going on?  I think this is a problem with my understanding of how these queue's work with resque-scheduler. I assumed that if the queues were list-like objects then I could operate on them , but it appears that it a symbol instead of something with methode like include? I assume the << notation for adding something to it is also invalid. 
Also please advise if this isn't the way to go about handling this kind of job scheduling

Comment: Have you restarted your app after adding the `gather` method to `SchedulerJob`?

Comment: Nice, so that changed the error message, but now I think Ive encountered a fundamental misunderstanding of how resque-scheduler works. updating question body to reflect that

Comment: I've posted an answer to your original question below. If you're having new issues now, it may be best to open a new question focused on your current issue (i.e., how to use resque-scheduler properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you may have not restarted your Rails app after adding the new method `gather` to the `SchedulerJob` module. Try restarting your app to resolve this.

You may also be able to add the directory containing your Resque worker to Rails' `watchable_dirs` array so that changes you make to Resque worker modules in development don't require restarting your app. See this blog post for details:

> http://wondible.com/2012/01/13/rails-3-2-autoloading-in-theory/