# Enqueue_at(..) error in rails app. Resque scheduler raises NoQueueError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I keep getting this error while trying to use ResqueScheduler enqueue_at

```
Resque::NoQueueError in QuestionsController#create
Jobs must be placed onto a queue.
```

Here is the class that's calling it: note the after_create callback.

The reason the error is raised in the Questions controller is because there is a callback   `on_create`  for `Question` which in turn, creates an `Assignment` for users.

This is a follow-up issue from this post:

[Strange behavior with a resque scheduler job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857412/strange-behavior-with-a-resque-scheduler-job)

I've tried to follow the examples givien in this video: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=comments

. . .as well as reading basically everything I can find on Resque scheduler online, (including their documentation here: https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler)

I am reasonably confident that I am doing this right and pretty frustrated at this time. This seems to be a pretty rare error online with little documentation.

```
    require "scheduler_job"
    class Assignment  ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :question
      attr_accessible :title, :body, :user_id, :question_id , :response , :correct
      after_create :queue_assignments
      before_destroy :remove_from_queue


      def grade
        self.correct = (response == self.question.solution) unless response == nil
      end

      def queue_assignments
        Resque.enqueue_at(self.question.schedule , SchedulerJob , :id => self.id)
      end
      def remove_from_queue
        Resque.remove_delayed(SchedulerJob, :id => self.id)
      end
      def sendAlertEmail
        QuestionMailer.question(self)
      end
      def as_json(options={})
        {
          :correct => correct,
          :created_at =>  created_at,
          :id => id, 
          :question_id => question_id,
          :response => response ,
          :updated_at => updated_at,
          :user_id => user_id,
          :question => self.question
        }
      end
    end
```

And here is the job:

```
    require 'Assignment'
    require 'QuestionMailer'
    # this didnt work when i changed it to a class either
    module SchedulerJob


      #this didnt work with :ready_queue either but I dont know what the difference is
      @ready_queue = "ready_queue"
      def self.perform(id)
        @assignment=Assignment.find_by_id(id)
        @assignment.sendAlertEmail
      end


    end
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok so after a ton of troubleshooting and banging my head against the walls, I finally got it to work.

The instance variable Must be named`@queue`. The problem was that I was naming it `@ready_queue`. I guess resque scheduler requires this. Anyway. It seems to be working now. on to the next bug.